# Cannot connect through tcp remotely

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I’m developing an app that connects on port 9050 through the public ip of my server. It works fine on lan but if I’m connected on a different network it fails what can I do to fix this?

Comment: How are we supposed to know your network topology and firewall rules? What/where is "my server"? What do you mean by "different network"?

Comment: please read this [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

first try from Command Prompt this command: telnet ip 9050
if it working means the port 9050 between your pc and the server already opened , otherwise you should check why and where the port is blocked (may be firewall in this case you need to create rule in firewall to pass ).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any code to go by and I know nothing about your network configuration, but I'll tell you what I generally do when debugging a network-enabled app. First, look at your firewall rules. This will obviously vary depending on what OS you're using but on Windows 10 application-specific permissions are located in `Control Panel > System and Security > Windows Defender Firewall > Advanced Settings`.

After making sure your app can get through your devices' firewall, check the router settings next. Your packets may not getting by whatever inbuilt security protocols are in place. Since your program works with LAN but not over the Internet, this is a distinct possibility. Also, depending on your network configuration, port forwarding may be necessary; if you're sending data via a public IP address, the router needs some way to know which device on the local network needs to be receiving it. Additionally, if you're trying to connect to your server from the same network you're hosting it on, make sure you use the IP loopback address, which I believe is always 127.0.0.1, or in C# `IPAddress.Loopback`. Public addresses often won't work when connecting to a local host.

---

If you're still having problems, I recommend using [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/). It's an advanced diagnostics tool that tells you exactly what is being sent and received over your network, and can help pinpoint otherwise hard to spot issues.